# как вывести не дату файлов,а их название

Tags: bat, dos

Были попытки подобного `for /f "skip=2" %i in ('dir') do @echo %i` но выводит только дату были попытки с отрицательным числом но выходит ошибка   `Непредвиденное появление: ".`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто вывести?

```
@echo off    
dir /B /R c:\Path\to\folder
```